Deriving a characteristic function of the primes from the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function
Chebyshev's logarithmic prime counting function $\psi (x)$, also called second Chebyshev function, makes it particularly simple to demonstrate how the zeta zeros "encode" the prime distribution, see e.g. this article. The animation at the very bottom of the article can easily be reproduced - at least as a static image - with just a few lines of Python code.
A natural follow-up question - although of course without any practical use - for me was to ask how this approach can be turned into a characteristic function of the primes.
By differentiating the original equation $$\psi_{0}(x) = x - \ln(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{x^{2}}\bigg) - \sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho},$$ then removing parts that hardly contribute, and finally "normalising" it as good as I could so far, I came up with this function, or rather this family of functions:
$$\chi_{k}(x) = \left( \frac{x}{2 \ln x} - \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln x} \sum_{\rho \leq \rho_{k}} \cos(\textrm{Im }\rho \ln x) \right) \frac{\ln k}{\sqrt{k}}$$
where $\rho$ are the nontrivial zeros (with positive imaginary part) of the zeta function, and $\rho_{k}$ is the $k$th such zero.
The final factor $\ln k/\sqrt{k}$ is just a raw guess for how to keep the function values in a limited region for different values of $k$.
So function $\chi_{k}(x)$ uses the first $k$ (imaginary positive) nontrivial zeros of the zeta function to "detect" if a number is a prime number. It's of course not a characteristic function of the primes yet, but only a precursor. It's a continuous function that within a certain range has sharp positive peaks when $n$ is a prime, and if we could always (for any $k$) determine a valid threshold as well as a maximum $n$ for which using $k$ zeros is sufficient, it could easily be turned into such a characteristic function for this range, and possibly as a limit into a characteristic function of all primes.
Here a plot of $\chi_{600}(x)$:

Using the arbitrary threshold .5, $\chi_{600}(x)$ precisely detects all 62 primes $p_i\leqslant300$, meaning that if you plug a natural number $n\leqslant 300$ into the function, its value will be $>.5$ if and only if $n$ is a prime.
The problem is that when increasing k, the threshold slowly decreases, which means that my "normalization" efforts don't work yet as intended. E.g. for k = 1000 the threshold rather has to be something like 0.4 within the range n <= 300.
My questions are:

Any ideas how those $\chi _{k}(x)$ could be normalized more appropriately, or - basically the same thing - how a threshold and validity range could be determined for arbitrary values of k?
Do those $\chi _{k}(x)$ functions make sense at all?
Is there a better way to derive a characteristic function of the primes from the setting described above?


The standard way to compute the prime-counting $\pi(x)$ from the zeta-zeros is to use the explicit formula for Riemann's prime-power counting function $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{1<n\le x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$ rather than the explicit formula for the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)$ (see Formulas for prime-counting functions). The functions $\Pi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ are related via their first-order derivatives as follows: $\Pi'(x)=\frac{1}{\log(x)} \psi'(x)$.

Your formula has peaks at prime-powers as well as primes since $\psi(x)$ (and $\Pi(x)$) takes steps at prime-powers as well as primes. Your question overlaps this MSE question.
